# Integrate altavault with openstack swift

Tags: storage, openstack

I want to configure OpenStack Swift (Object storage) as Cloud Provider on Netapp AltaVault with Authentication Method as Username/Password.

To integrate AltaVault with OpenStack Swift, what do I need to do?